# DataTables warning: table id=tableid - Ajax error. in asp.net-MVC project

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In asp.net-MVC project I take jason data from api and show it in view using jQuery datatable. It work perfect in my localhost, but after releasing it browser give me an error. error massage is...

DataTables warning: table id=tableid - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

i also check my browser console it shows..

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - http://masum626-001-site1.htempurl.com/api/boardofdirectors?_=1512147088008

my api

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBoardOfDirector()
    {
        var boardOfDirector =
            _context.BoardOfDirectors.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<BoardOfDirector, BoardOfDirectorDto>);
        return Ok(boardOfDirector);
    }
```

and view

```
<table id="tableid" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>Educational Qualification</th>
    <th>Catagory</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#tableid").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/boardofdirectors",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "name",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='/boardofdirector/edit/" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</a>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "designation"
                },
                {
                    data: "educationalQualification"
                },
                {
                    data: "catagory"
                },
                {
                    data: "comment"
                },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render:function(data) {
                    return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-director-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                    }   
                }
                ]
        });

        $("#tableid").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
            var button = $(this);

            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/boardofdirectors/" + button.attr("data-director-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```